# How to defer the resolving of classes?

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, ninject

**This is my scenario:**

I have an application like this:

*I Use Ninject as my DI Container and I am working with WPF*

[image]

1-There is `ClassB` which is injected into `ClassA` Which is Injected into `1stViewModel` which is injected into `1stView`

2- Again There is `ClassR` which is injected into `ClassQ` Wich is Injected into `2ndViewModel` which is injected into `2ndView`

3-And this happens for the 3rd and 4th window

**Questions:**

1- What can I do to Resolve the Classes when they are needed (when user clicks on 1st Button or 2nd) not in my composition root?

2- If I don't Inject my `ViewModels` into my Views and I want to make new instance of my `ViewModel` inside my View, obviously it needs a parameter which is `IClassA` for the 1st and `IClassQ` for the 2nd for example. How can I do it?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure it can do what you need, but you can have a look into Lazy initialization: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286.aspx and make your containers use and inject the `Lazy<T>` wrapper.

Comment: Relevant link: [ninject.extensions.factory/Lazy](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki/Lazy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ninject.extensions.factory with that you can define `ToFactory` bindings for a given interface you define or you can inject a `Lazy<T>` in your constructor. More details see the wiki of the extension here https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki

Answer (score 2):

(Was an [answer to a duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17806666/11635))

+1 on Daniel's answer - it's 100% correct. Just one explication and an example.

Where it's appropriate (you want just in time creation *and caching* of a single dependency instance), `Lazy` is the best choice. Not bindings needed, you just need the extension to be present.

The obvious difference between `Lazy<IFoo>` and a Factory that creates `IFoo`s is that you'll always have the same instance whereas a Factory'd purpose is to create fresh ones.

If you simply want a factory to create a Foo for you instead of using `Func<IFoo>`, you can use exactly the following:

```
interface IFooFactory
{
   IFoo CreateFoo();
}

Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>();
Bind<IFooFactory>().ToFactory();
```

The **`.ToFactory()`** bit does all the implementation behind the scenes (i.e. it creates interceptors and Castle Dynamic Proxy with a bodies that achieve the following:

```
class _SomethingAnonymous : IFooFactory
{
    readonly IResolutionRoot _resolutionRoot; 

    public _SomethingAnonymous(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
    {
        _resolutionRoot=resolutionRoot; 
    }

    IFoo CreateFoo() 
    { 
         _resolutionRoot.Get<IFoo>();
    }
 }
```

and `Bind`s `IFooFactory` to it.

Having this code not be concrete means that (if necessary as you develop your code) provides a variety of ways to move beyond basic creation with no parameters.

Comment: I don't Understand where is the `Implementation` of the `IFooFactory Interface`?

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh The implementation is codegenned using Castle Dynamic Proxy into a temporary assembly. The wiki shows code equivalent to what you would have to write. (as it is now, it is `readonly IResolutionRoot _resolutionRoot; ctor(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot) {_resolutionRoot=resolutionRoot}; IFoo CreateFoo() { _resolutionRoot.Get<IFoo>();}}`). I tried pretty hard to make this clear in the wiki, but clearly it's not clear enough. Can you read it top to bottom and find something and make it bold please?

Comment: Oh my God you mean It understands the names and generates the code behind the scenes automatically?????? @Ruben I really Like to help and improve the wiki but at first I have to fully understand that myself. But surly I would do it.

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh That's fine, there's no rush! Have a look in the `src` for `Ninject.Extensions.Factory` BTW to see how it works -- it's just code :)

Comment: I know and I'm sorry that I am disturbing you :( but there is another question. what if I have `ClassA` and `ClassB` which are the implementation of `IFoo` and I want to inject a `List<IFoo>` to another class lets say `ClassX`. Now I want to be able to Resolve just `ClassB` in runtime. how can I understand which one in the list is `ClassB` before I have Resolve the classes?

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh for that, you reference `.Named("XX")` `Bind`ings using [the `GetXXX` convention supported by the Factory extension](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki/Factory-interface%3A-Referencing-Named-Bindings). But the best solution depends on your *actual* problem. That probably **is** a separate Question. (If you ask for a `List`/`IEnumerable`/`Array<T>`, the instances get spun up which is rarely a good idea). (AutoFac and MEF both support asking for metadata instead of instances but I'm not aware of an extension to do that in Ninject.